# Syntax errors when attempting to use ifdef

Tags: perl, syntax-error

I have:

```
if($^O eq 'MSWin32'){
  export WINDOWS=1
else{
  export UNIX=1
}

=begin WINDOWS
  use feature qw(switch);
=cut
=begin UNIX
  use Switch;
=cut
```

And I get:

> syntax error at C:\build.pl line 6, near "else"
>   BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at C:\build.pl line 17.

Comment: It has been said below, but I'll say it here: Don't use switch in any form. If you're going to rewrite your program anyway, rewrite it to use if-elsif-else instead. There is no benefit to using switch (either version), and it is both deprecated and experimental.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Including bourne shell commands in a Perl program... not likely to work.

```
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
   $ENV{WINDOWS}=1;
}else{
   $ENV{UNIX}=1;
}
```

I don't understand what follows. Then, you mark code as documentation, but that doesn't appear to be what you are trying to do. You appear to be trying to do the following:

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', 'feature', qw( switch );
use if $^O ne 'MSWin32', 'Switch';
```

But that makes no sense. The switch feature and the Switch module are in no way interchangeable, and both work on Windows and on non-Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks. I've ran into a snag in that the Unix perl is outdated, and updating it may not be possible at this time. Because of that, I was going to use switch sytax for Unix, and Given/When syntax for windows. So there would be multiple `if $^O eq 'MSWin32'` statements in the script. Probably not a very elegant way..

Comment: and actually my script doesn't even compile now.. so this whole question may be moot.

Comment: Like I said, the switch feature and the Switch module are in no way interchangeable

Comment: Can i not just `use Switch` on unix, and then have some sort of #ifdef to determine whether the system is Unix or not, and if so, execute my `swich($action) ... case "blah", etc.` instead of the section of `given($action) ... when("blah"), etc.`?

Comment: Like you already said, `swich() { case () {} case () {} }` doesn't compile without the feature enabled. Why are you now asking if you can just skip execution??

Comment: In languages like C++ this is possible. I guess it's not in perl? I just wanted to conditionally (a) `use <either|or>`, and (b) when it came to the chunk of code that relies on those modules, have the interpreter know which chunk was "live code" and which wasn't.

Comment: I showed you how to do (a), and you could do (b) just like you would in C: use `cpp` and `#ifdef`. But it's silly to write the code twice just to avoid the just-as-simple `if`

Comment: @MrDuk The `switch` feature is experimental and the author of `Switch.pm` recommends against using it in production code. Not only that, but you're assuming that any time your code runs on *nix that it will be on an old version of Perl, which is a terrible assumption. Just use `if/elsif/else`, which is not experimental or buggy and will work on any Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the `if (...) {` block by putting a `}` before `else`; i.e., change this:

```
else{
```

to this:

```
}else{
```